# Spring is not able to instantiate bean

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, jpa, jersey

I have developed a RESTful web service using Jersey 1.14 implementation. I am using Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE to load the webservice. The webservice takes a json input and uses a DAO to update the db using JPA.

While the client class successfully invokes the `RLWebService`, it is not able to get an instance of the `RLServiceDao`. Both the WebService and the DAO classes have the the relevant properties and getter/setters.

Below is my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.clsa.gcp.cms.server.ws.rlwebservice.AppInitializer"></bean>

<bean id="rlServiceDAO" class="com.server.dao.RLServiceDAO">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="rlWebService" class="com.server.ws.rlwebservice.RLWebService">
    <property name="rlServiceDAO" ref="rlServiceDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="cmsdataSource">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="${jdbc.database}" />
            <property name="showSql" value="${jdbc.showSql}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <!--  prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop-->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">${net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">${hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">${hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">${hibernate.max_fetch_depth}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">${hibernate.use_outer_join}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">${hibernate.cache.region.factory_class}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>`
```

I have written a simple client class which calls this web service:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8888/gcpcms/api/rlservice");

    connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(600000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(600000);
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write(jsonObject.toString());
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    String output;

    while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
    System.out.println("RLService REST Service Invoked Successfully..");
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nError while calling RLService REST Service");
    System.out.println(e);
} finally {
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the error message?

Comment: The stack trace will help us debug in assisting with an answer.